# How do I add a certificate to keychain access?

Tags: ios, ios5

I am having the hardest time having a valid setup. Earlier I had requested a certificate in keychain. It then made me download a "CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest" file that I uploaded to my company portal in iOS member center.

They then validated it and I could then download a "developer_identity.cer" that I installed in keychain. I then went to my XCode organizer and did a "Automatic Device Provisioning" and it downloaded profiles that had a warning about "valid signing identity not found".

As a last resort I deleted all the certificates and profiles off my Mac and somewhat have a clean slate since I had multiple profiles earlier which I figured were screwing things up.

I know have on my desktop the "CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest" file and the "developer_identity.cer" only. How do I get this all to work the right way?

Thank You

Comment: How is this related to Objective-C??? About the certificate file, you should definitively give drag&drop a try...

Comment: Macmade, as its obvious I am new due to the nature of my question...Would you kindly elaborate on the drag and drop? Much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

Double-clicking on the certificate will open it in Keychain Access and import it automatically.

Comment: Tried that. So now I see a developer profile under "certificates" along with Apple Worldwide Developer Relations. Should I now go back and try to refresh the provisioning page?

Comment: I also do not see anything under "developer profile" in XCode Organizer